# RSVP guest database column won't increment by one after pressing the submit button

Tags: php

I am trying to write PHP code that will increase the count by 1 when the user clicks RSVP. As of now, when I click the RSVP button I get a message that says that the RSVP was successful but when I check the database the RSVP count is still 0. Here is the code that is supposed to carry out this function.

```
<?php
$servername = "db.sice.indiana.edu";
$username = "i494f20_tywinfre";
$password = "my+sql=i494f20";
$dbname = "i494f20_tywinfre";

// Create Connection

$conn = mysqli_connect("db.sice.indiana.edu", "i494f20_tywinfre", 
"my+sql=i494f20_tywinfre", "i494f20_tywinfre");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$id = $_POST["EVENTID"];


$sql = "SELECT CURRENTGUEST, MAXGUEST FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENTID 
$id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows ($result) > 0) {

//OUTPUT DATA OF EACH ROW

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  

if($row['CURRENTGUEST']<$row['MAXGUEST']) {
$id = $_POST["EVENTID"];
$t = $row['CURRENTGUEST'];


$query = "UPDATE EVENTS SET CURRENTGUEST = CURRENTGUEST + 1 
WHERE EVENTID = $id";

echo "RSVP successful";
}
}

} else {

echo "Event is full";

}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is my code I am not sure what the problem could be thank you for the help!

Comment: You are not executing the update query

Comment: As stated above, the $query  = "UPDATE EVENTS"... line is just defining a variable called "query", not executing anything. you need to add a line like 
 mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting the query variable with the update statement, but you are never executing it.

Add

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

After your `$query` line.

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

You should also check the result of the update query to ensure that the RSVP was done correctly, otherwise user will ger RSVP sucesfull always, even if the query fails.